# Same code on different server throwing errors

Tags: php

I am currently working on a PHP Application, but after resetting my server and re-uploading the code, 
I am receiving errors.

I have no trouble on my localhost server, which is running PHP 5.4.19, but when I upload it to my server, running PHP 5.5.9, I get `syntax error, unexpected '}'` errors at the end of almost every if/while statement.

The first error is on line 190

```
if($game['status'] == "3"){
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `played_cards` WHERE `game` = '" . $_SESSION['game_id'] . "'");
    while($c = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
        if($c['user'] == $game['winner']){
            ?>
                <div class="col-md-2"><div class="alert alert-info"><b><?php echo $c['card']; ?></b></div></div>
            <?php
        }else{
            ?>
                <div class="col-md-2"><div class="alert alert-info"><?php echo $c['card']; ?>        </div></div>
            <?php
        }
    }
} #line 190
```

But, If I comment out all but the first and last line in the code above, the error goes away. However, if I add something as simple as

```
if(true){
}
```

between the two lines, I get the error again.

Any ideas as to what is happening?

Comment: post code that is throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure that there was no .htaccess file changing the config of the server, failing that please post some code so we can have a better look. It could be possible that you are using the alternative syntax for PHP if statements. Try looking here

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: All I have in my .htaccess file is some rewrite rules